# Handling conditional statements while designing a logger like class?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

How do you handle the conditional statements while designing a class like log4j?

Taking log4j example, a class can have different levels(Info, Warning, Error, others...). Now to print for the different levels you would need different methods for each level. So there could be a basic design as follows:

```
public class CustomLogger {

    enum Level{
        INFO, WARNING, ERROR;
    }

    private Level level;

    public CustomLogger(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void info(String s){
        if(level == Level.INFO || level == Level.WARNING || level == Level.ERROR){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public void warning(String s){
        if(level == Level.WARNING || level == Level.ERROR){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public void error(String s){
        if(level == Level.ERROR){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this design I guess is that it has way too many if conditions and in case I need to add a new state I would have to modify all the if cases. So what I think could be a better design is as follows:

There is a `State` super class which is extended by class `Info`, class `Warning` and class `Error`. The `State` class has methods `printInfo()`, `printWarning()` and `printError()`. All the subclasses implement these methods and leave blank the once they need. As an example class `Warning` would look like:

```
class Warning extends State{

    public void printInfo(String s){
        //don't print
    }

    public void printWarning(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public void printError(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Now the `CustomLogger` will have an association with `State` which will be injected to it at some moment and all the methods in `CustomLogger` will call methods of `State` class implementation. Something like:

```
public class CustomLogger {

    private State state;

    public CustomLogger(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void info(String s){
        state.printInfo(s);
    }

    public void warning(String s){
        state.printWarning(s);
    }

    public void error(String s){
        state.printError(s);
    }

}
```

Even though this eliminates the conditional cases, but it induces a dependency of the methods call. If I add a new `State` then that states `printState()` method would have to added to every subclass which I guess is not a good practice. What else can be done in such cases?

Comment: I really think you need the [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) refactoring

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I looked into it, but could not think how I can make it work it in this case. I could have used it if all the states do independent work, but here they are related. If level in `Info`, I need to allow `Warning` and `Error` and so on and so forth.

Comment: If I recall correctly log4j has a method that takes in the level and the message `log(Level, String)` so the checks for the level desired versus the set level are all in one place. Then the methods like `info(String)` are syntactic sugar that call into the other method.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer, in this case, depends on how your system's requirements could change in the future. Even if you follow the [`Open/close principle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) you cannot prevent every possible scenario which violates this principle, so you try to cover in your design those that you think are more likely to appear.

Anyhow, a good solution for your case study would be similar to the one implemented by Java [`Logger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html). Where a numeric values is associated to the `Logger` level (every possible `Level` has its value) that allow you to check if the current `Logger` should write anything to the log with a single `if`. Besides it is very easy to extend its behaviour without modifying the current code.

For example when you call `Logger#info(String)`:

```
public void info(String msg) {
    log(Level.INFO, msg);
}
```

Method `log` is as follows:

```
public void log(Level level, String msg) {
    if (!isLoggable(level)) {
        return;
    }
    // do any logging you want here
}
```

And finally the key `isLoggable`:

```
public boolean isLoggable(Level level) {
    if (level.intValue() < levelValue || levelValue == offValue) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where `levelValue` is "the current effective level value" of the `Logger`.